# fusion table query

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I have a very large fusion table.Now,i want to query that based on user requirements.My user interface should have one drop down box to select the name of the column and another drop down box for selecting query condition('=','>','<') and one more text box for column value's.please,can any one hep me.Map should be loaded based on this input.

Answer (score 0):

user1225902: You need to call the onLoad function from during page load. I had thesame problem.