# Drop down fusion table

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

How to select user defined column using drop down box from fusion table which has around 50 columns.That column should be used for further queries.Is there any way to do it.I am new to Google map API.

Comment: How is this different than the [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9907101/1211981) you asked yesterday, which has been answered?

Comment: I want to select column using drop down list from my web page.All these examples are explaining only how to select values that are inside particular column.But i want to select name of the column that is used for query also from user.I want to make my user to select any column from my fusion table.That's what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying you don't want to hard-code the column names in your html?  You want to get the columns names via javascript?  If so you'll need to use the JSONP API.  I've posted [several examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9775952/1211981) which could be modified to just retrieve the column names from a FT.
Change the query to:

```
var query = "SELECT * FROM " + table_id + " LIMIT 1";
```

Your JSONP callback (called example_dataHandler(d) in those examples) will get an array of column names:

```
 var colnames = [];
 colnames = d.table.cols;
```